# pg_dump: too many command line arguments

Tags: postgresql, dump, database-backups, pg-dump

what is wrong with this command:

```
pg_dump -U postgres -W admin --disable-triggers -a -t employees -f D:\ddd.txt postgres
```

This is giving error of too many command-line arguments

Answer (score 48):

Looks like its the -W option. There is no value to go with that option.

```
-W, --password           force password prompt (should happen automatically)
```

If you want to run the command without typing is a password, use a .pgpass file.
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-pgpass.html

Comment: @BhargavGor: omit `-W admin`, not just `-W`

Answer (score 27):

For posterity, note that pg_dump and pg_restore (and many other commands) cannot process long hyphens that word processors create. If you are cut-pasting command lines from a word processor, be sure it hasn't converted your hyphens to something else in editing. Else you will get command lines that look correct but hopelessly confuse the argument parsers in these tools.

Comment: This helped me.

Answer (score 22):

pg_dump and pg_restore need to ask password on commandline, if you put it command, they always give "too many command-line arguments" error. You can use below for setting related environment variable in commandline or batch file:

```
"SET PGPASSWORD=<password>"
```

so that you are not asked to enter password manually in your batch file. They use given environment variable.

Comment: This was so tech. It saved me from writing from a terrible me expect/spawn bash script. Thank you.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The other answers are simply solving typos.

Answer (score 11):

Instead of passing password with `-W` flag start with setting temporary variable for postgres:

```
PGPASSWORD="mypass" pg_dump -U postgres--disable-triggers -a -t employees -f D:\ddd.txt postgres
```

Comment: This worked, but needed single quotation for "mypass".

Answer (score 6):

`-W`   -> will prompt for a password
to take full DB dump
use some thing like

```
pg_dump -h 192.168.44.200 -p 5432 -U postgres -W -c -C -Fc -f C:\MMM\backup10_3.backup DATABASE_NAME
```

Answer (score 5):

I got this from copy-pasting, where 1 of the dashes were different.

Was: `–-host=` (first dash i a "long" dash)
Corrected to `--host=` solved it

Comment: dude, i'd fking kiss if you were here! lol.  watch out for TextEdit auto-correct

Comment: Stupid problems... I had -jobs instead of --jobs.

Answer (score 3):

Additionally, if you don't want password prompt, use connection string directly.

```bash
pg_dump 'postgresql://<username>:<password>@localhost:5432/<dbname>'
```

So, combination with options in original question,

```bash
pg_dump 'postgresql://postgres:<password>@localhost:5432/postgres' --table='"employees"' --format='t' --file='D:\ddd.txt' --data-only --disable-triggers
```

**Don't forget to use quotes when you have letter-casing issues**

reference:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html
- [Postgres dump specific table with a capital letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905162/postgres-dump-specific-table-with-a-capital-letter)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to add `~/.pgpass` file with content like this:

```
hostname:port:database:username:password
```

read more [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html)

Answer (score 0):

2021-11-30, pg v12, windows 10

```
pg_dump -U postgres -W -F t postgres > C:\myfolder\pg.tar
```

`-U "postgres"` as username,

`-W` to prompt for psd,

`-F t` means format is .tar,

`> C:\myfolder\pg.tar` is the destination path and filename