# Postgres dump specific table with a capital letter

Tags: postgresql, shell

I am trying to perform a postgres dump of a specific table using -t. However, the table has a capital letter in it and I get a "No matching tables were found." I tried using quotations and double quotations around the table name but they did not work. How can I get pg to recognize the capitals? Thanks!

```
pg_dump -h hostname dbname -t tableName > pgdump.sql
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Here is the complete command to dump your table in plain mode:

```
pg_dump --host localhost --port 5432 --username "postgres" --role "postgres"  --format plain  --file "complete_path_file" --table "schema_name.\"table_name\"" "database_name"
```

OR  you can just do:

```
pg_dump -t '"tablename"' database_name > data_base.sql
```

Look to the last page here: [Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html)

Comment: In windows it still doesn't work.

`> pg_dump --table="\"Accounts\"" -U postgres -d helium2 > dump.s
ql`

Gives the following error:

`pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR:  invalid regular expression: parentheses () not balanced
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: SELECT c.oid
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE c.relkind in ('r', 'S', 'v', 'm', 'f')
  AND c.relname ~ E'^(\\accounts\\)$'
  AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)`

Comment: Adding the Schema is VERY VITAL

Answer (score 15):

The above solutions do not work for me under Windows 7 x64. PostgreSQL 9.4.5. But this does, at last (sigh):

### `-t "cms.\"FooContents\""`

either...

```
pg_dump.exe -p 8888 --username=user -t "cms.\"FooContents\"" basdb
```

...or...

```
pg_dump.exe -p 8888 --username=user -table="cms.\"FooContents\"" basdb
```

Comment: This is also the only solution that worked for me on a Raspbian, thanks.

Comment: This also worked in Windows 10 x64 and PostgreSQL 12. Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need to quote the full table spec unless it contains whitespace.  That's a command processor thing, not pg_dump.  
  
  `pg_dump.exe -p 8888 --username=user --table=cms.\"FooContents\" basdb`

Answer (score 6):

Inside a cmd window, I had to put three (!) double quotes around the table name if it countains upper case letters.
Example
pg_dump -t """Colors""" database > database.colors.psql

Comment: I forgot to mention this is Microsoft Windows 7. Single quotes don't work here.

Comment: The three double quotes thing also works perfectly well on Windows 10. None of the other solutions worked for me except for this one.

Answer (score 1):

**Powershell**

*the good (shortest)*

```
& 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\pg_dump.exe' -d db_name -t '\"CasedTableName\"'
```

*the bad (requires --%)*

```
& 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\pg_dump.exe' --% -d db_name -t "\"CasedTableName\""
```

*the ugly (requires `")*

```
& 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\pg_dump.exe' -d db_name -t "\`"CasedTableName\`""
```

The main point of confusion for me was the absolute necessity of having `\"` in there.  I assumed that maybe there was a weird bug in the way powershell or psql was parsing the arguments, but it turns out it's explained [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7.2#passing-arguments-that-contain-quote-characters):

> Some native commands expect arguments that contain quote characters. Normally, PowerShell's command line parsing removes the quote character you provided. The parsed arguments are then joined into a single string with each parameter separated by a space. This string is then assigned to the Arguments property of a ProcessStartInfo object. Quotes within the string must be escaped using extra quotes or backslash (\) characters.

And of course [ProcessStartInfo.Arguments Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments?view=net-6.0#remarks) tells us:

> To include quotation marks in the final parsed argument, triple-escape each mark.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
pg_dump -f file.sql -U user -t 'schema.\"Table\"' database
```

Answer (score 0):

As part of a node script I had to surround with single and double quotes, e.g.

```
` ... --table 'public."IndexedData"'`
```

The accepted solution worked in a bash console, but not as part of a node script, only the single quote approach.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Dirk Zabel suggestion, the following worked for me:

**Windows 10 CMD**

```
pg_dump -d "MyDatabase" -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres --schema=public -t """TableName""" > TableName.sql
```

**Bash**

```
pg_dump -d "MyDatabase" -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres --schema=public -t "\"TableName\"" > TableName.sql
```