# postgresql db take backup and restore with data

Tags: postgresql

i would like to take backup and restore of my postgresql database automatically.

1. take backup automatically from postgresql with cron trigger in windows pc
2. later i will do restore when ever it required.

i have below bat commands to take back up of my database

```
F:
cd F:\softwares\postgresql-12.1-3-windows-x64-binaries\pgsql\bin
pg_dump.exe -U postgres -s fuelman > E:\fuel_man_prod_backup\prod.sql
cmd /k
```

but i am getting

> pg_dump: error: too many command-line arguments (first is "-s")

also i need to take both schema structure with data.

Edit :-
removed password -W

Comment: -s means schema only. And when only have a backup of the schema, you don't have the data. And it looks like a \ is missing in your command, but I'm not familiar with Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. "Too many command line" probably is due to -W option; the string "postgres" after -W is interpreted as db name, so following -s gives error. Anyway, when running pg_dump from a script you must not use -W; use .pgpass file or set PGPASSWORD environment variable (look at [pg_dump: too many command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865596/pg-dump-too-many-command-line-arguments) for more details).
2. As for Frank Heikens comment, if you need to dump both object definition and data, avoid -s option. [pg_dump documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) is quite clear.

Comment: yeah i removed -w and now it takes dump of object definition, but i need to enter password manually, is there a ways to take password input from cmd automatically?

Comment: ok got it .pgpass would work..

Comment: As already written: use .pgpass file or set PGPASSWORD environment variable